# Safety of Thread.current[] usage in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thread-safety

I keep getting conflicting opinions on the practice of storing information in the `Thread.current` hash (e.g., the current_user, the current subdomain, etc.). The technique has been proposed as a way to simplify later processing within the model layer (query scoping, auditing, etc.).

- [Why are my thread variables intermittent in Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217911/why-are-my-thread-variables-intermittent-in-rails)
- [Alternative to using Thread.current in API wrapper for Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7509883/alternative-to-using-thread-current-in-api-wrapper-for-rails)
- [Are Thread.current[] values and class level attributes safe to use in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659221/are-thread-current-values-and-class-level-attributes-safe-to-use-in-rails)

Many consider the practice unacceptable because it breaks the MVC pattern.
Others express concerns about reliability/safety of the approach, and my 2-part question focuses on the latter aspect.

1. Is the `Thread.current` hash guaranteed to be available and private to one and only one response, throughout its entire cycle?
2. I understand that a thread, at the end of a response, may well be handed over to other incoming requests, thereby leaking any information stored in `Thread.current`. Would clearing such information before the end of the response (e.g. by executing `Thread.current[:user] = nil` from a controller's `after_filter`) suffice in preventing such security breach?

Thanks!
Giuseppe

Comment: Check out "Getting dirty with Thread.current" section here. http://m.onkey.org/thread-safety-for-your-rails. That was written by one of the Jruby authors. #1 ROR code itself uses Thread.current for I18N and time_zone. Does that speak about its guarantee?  #2. If #1 is true then it is sufficient.

Comment: In the post you link to, the examples deal exclusively with the controller layer, and the proposed solution is obviously appropriate. I suspect, though, that what most people would be interested in is a clean way to give access to models to 1-2 pieces of information normally precluded to them, without adding extra parameters to each call to models. In this respect, all those big scary "stay away from Thread.current" warning signs without specific reasons why have so far left me uncertain. Thanks

Answer (score 55, accepted):

There is not an specific reason to stay away from thread-local variables, the main issues are:

- it's harder to test them, as you will have to remember to set the thread-local variables when you're testing out code that uses it
- classes that use thread locals will need knowledge that these objects are not **available** to them but inside a thread-local variable and this kind of indirection usually breaks the [law of demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)
- not cleaning up thread-locals might be an issue if your framework reuses threads (the thread-local variable would be already initiated and code that relies on **||=** calls to initialize variables might fail

So, while it's not completely out of question to use, the **best** approach is not to use them, but from time to time you hit a wall where a thread local is going to be the simplest possible solution without changing quite a lot of code and you will have to compromise, have a less than perfect object oriented model with the thread local or changing quite a lot of code to do the same.

So, it's mostly a matter of thinking which is going to be the best solution for your case and if you're really going down the thread-local path, I'd surely advise you to do it with blocks that remember to clean up after they are done, like the following:

```
around_filter :do_with_current_user

def do_with_current_user
    Thread.current[:current_user] = self.current_user
    begin
        yield
    ensure
        Thread.current[:current_user] = nil
    end      
end
```

This ensures the thread local variable is cleaned up before being used if this thread is recycled.

Comment: Using an around filter with an ensure block will mess with exception handling/logging if you're not very careful.  Check out RequestStore in Dejan's answer for a middleware-based, cleaner solution.

Comment: May have been my approach to the problem in that I was rescuing the exception first (rather than just ensuring as above).  The exception's call stack was getting reset to the location where I re-raised, messing up the Rails error log and elsewhere.  I ended up manually dumping the captured exception to the log file myself to preserve it but it was ugly.  Using a middleware-based approach is much cleaner IMHO.

Comment: That's why that code above only has an `ensure` block and doesn't try to catch the exception.

Comment: Simple when you see it :)

Answer (score 25):

This little gem ensures your thread/request local variables not stick between requests: https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store

Answer (score 22):

The accepted answer covers the question but as Rails 5 now provides a "Abstract super class" [ActiveSupport::CurrentAttributes](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/current_attributes.rb) which uses Thread.current.

I thought I would provide a link to that as a possible([unpopular](https://ryanbigg.com/2017/06/current-considered-harmful)) solution.

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/current_attributes.rb

Answer (score 5):

The accepted answer is technically accurate, but as pointed out in the answer gently, and in http://m.onkey.org/thread-safety-for-your-rails not so gently:

**Don't use thread local storage, `Thread.current` if you don't absolutely have to**

The gem for [`request_store`](https://github.com/steveklabnik/request_store) is another solution (better) but just read the readme there for more reasons to stay away from thread local storage.

There is almost always a better way.

Comment: I'm using Unicorn with Rails Multi-tenant app.  Can you suggest an example of "better way" ?  Link you posted throws application error. Thanks.